# How do I float a <li> to the right in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've got a header that acts as table and I'm trying to **float the last li to the right**.

I've tried setting the padding-right % of the 5th li to appear at the end but obviously this isn't ideal as on other screens it causes issues. I've also tried to float it to the right, but it messes up the vertical alignment. Any suggestions?

[image]

```css
#header ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}

#header ul li { 
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Logo */
#header li:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 4%;
}

/* Back & Forward buttons */
#header li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 8.2%;
}

/* Search box */
#header li:nth-child(3) {
    padding-right: 4.5%;
}

/* Break line */
#header li:nth-child(4) {
    padding-right: 2%;
}

/* Icons */
#header li:nth-child(5) {}

/* Icons */
#header li:nth-child(6) {
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <!-- Logo -->
        <li width="10%"><div>B</div></li>
        <!-- Back / forward buttons -->
        <li>
            <i class="material-icons md-38 back-forward icn-hvr">chevron_left</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-38 back-forward icn-hvr">chevron_right</i>
        </li>
        <!-- Search box -->
        <li>
            <input type="search" id="search" size="30" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
        </li>
        <!-- Break line -->
        <li>
            <span class="hdr-break"></span>
        </li>
        <!-- Icons -->
        <li>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-stamp">add_location</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-map">map</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-hvr">business_center</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-hvr">notifications</i>
        </li>
        <!-- This should float right -->
        <li>
            <p>x</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried using text-align: right on the li element?

Comment: Please add a working code snippet so we have with what to work. Tried with the existing HTML/CSS but it doesn't render as the image you posted.

Comment: I'd try using `flex`. I don't think you'll be able to get this to work using tables like this. Can you set widths on each `li`?

Comment: All you need to do is to remove `float:left;` and add `display: table`. I posted an answer showing it works with that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your existing code, all you need to do is to remove `float:left;` and add `display: table`.

```
#header ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        ....
```

And here is your code snippet showing it.

```css
#header ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}

#header ul li { 
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Logo */
#header li:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 4%;
}

/* Back & Forward buttons */
#header li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 8.2%;
}

/* Search box */
#header li:nth-child(3) {
    padding-right: 4.5%;
}

/* Break line */
#header li:nth-child(4) {
    padding-right: 2%;
}

/* Icons */
#header li:nth-child(5) {}

/* Icons */
#header li:nth-child(6) {
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <!-- Logo -->
        <li width="10%"><div>B</div></li>
        <!-- Back / forward buttons -->
        <li>
            <i class="material-icons md-38 back-forward icn-hvr">chevron_left</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-38 back-forward icn-hvr">chevron_right</i>
        </li>
        <!-- Search box -->
        <li>
            <input type="search" id="search" size="30" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
        </li>
        <!-- Break line -->
        <li>
            <span class="hdr-break"></span>
        </li>
        <!-- Icons -->
        <li>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-stamp">add_location</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-map">map</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-hvr">business_center</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-hvr">notifications</i>
        </li>
        <!-- This should float right -->
        <li>
            <p>x</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about the solution too, but it's has a very different output although both table and flexbox can push the "x" to the far right correctly, I made the screenshots - http://i.imgur.com/wGvGfI7.png you can see it easily. Anyway OP would pick the one that works the best for his/her case.

Comment: `flex` is a better way to do it but couldn't post that as you already had ... :), so this was left as an option to touch as little as possible of the existing code, and the image you showed, that can of course be achieved using `display: table` too ... so I guess I need to give you an up vote :)

Comment: Thanks again... and agreed, it looks like OP was trying to get it done with table layout in the first place.

Comment: This actually worked best for me after some fiddling so thank you! I'm already using flexbox for the #header element, so this is an addition. If Pangloss's answer is recommended then I'll try make that work.

Comment: @LiamMacmillan If you need to support IE8,9, use this, if not, then `flex` is more modern and recommended, though doesn't solve your question better.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use flexbox, it can be done quite easily. Use `align-items: center;` will get the items vertically centered. With last item set to `margin-left: auto;` to send the "x" icon to the far right.

Run the snippet below and click "Full page" to see.

```css
#header ul {
    width: 100%;
    /* float: left; */
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#header ul li { 
    height: 100%;
    /* display: table-cell; */
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

/* Logo */
#header li:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 4%;
}

/* Back & Forward buttons */
#header li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 8.2%;
}

/* Search box */
#header li:nth-child(3) {
    padding-right: 4.5%;
}

/* Break line */
#header li:nth-child(4) {
    padding-right: 2%;
}

/* Icons */
#header li:nth-child(5) {}

/* Icons */
#header li:nth-child(6) {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <!-- Logo -->
        <li width="10%"><div>B</div></li>
        <!-- Back / forward buttons -->
        <li>
            <i class="material-icons md-38 back-forward icn-hvr">chevron_left</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-38 back-forward icn-hvr">chevron_right</i>
        </li>
        <!-- Search box -->
        <li>
            <input type="search" id="search" size="30" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
        </li>
        <!-- Break line -->
        <li>
            <span class="hdr-break"></span>
        </li>
        <!-- Icons -->
        <li>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-stamp">add_location</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-map">map</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-hvr">business_center</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-hvr">notifications</i>
        </li>
        <!-- This should float right -->
        <li>
            <p>x</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
#header li:last-child {
  right: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is use last-child. Right now you are using display: table-cell, switch it to inline-block and this will work.

CSS

```
 #header li:last-child { float: right; }

 #header ul li { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: That messes up the vertical alignment, as said in the question.

Comment: Did you read the question at all? Have you tested this code? If you make all of the `li` inline-block, then the vertical alignment doesn't work.

Comment: just add padding or margin set to 0 or auto to make it aligned vertically